# Is file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND) guaranteed to add/complete?

Tags: php

```
$result = file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "This should never happen";
}
```

Of course nothing is guaranteed, but if I use the above on every request to log something, will they all complete?

Ignore hardware and config issues, that's not my concern.

My concern is how will PHP handle writing so much to one file so often.

What about if I have thousands of requests per second?

I don't want any form of file lock, I want every single function call to register and append to the one file.

Comment: No. it's not guaranteed. The file might not be accessible (e.g. insufficient permissions on the containing directories), it might not be writeable (file itself is inaccessible). it might be locked by some OTHER process. The drive might be full. blah blah blah. If you expect to get thousands of requests, then you WILL have to lock the file. Anything else will just be begging for a corrupted file.

Comment: When I consider 'locking the file' I assume that means that other PHP/Apache requests won't be able to add data to the file whilst it's locked. Is this right? Are you saying that using file_put_contents on every request (thousands/second) isn't going to be reliable enough?

Comment: `file_put_contents('file.txt', $text, LOCK_EX|FILE_APPEND)`. boom, done. Because, yes, if two php processes happen to run simulataneously and both try to write to the file, you're going to get corruption. Unix doesn't care how many processes have a file open - it's up to those processes to handle concurrency, which is why there's the whole locking system.

Comment: So that would work? I'm confused about the 'lock' part. If one PHP request has locked the file won't other PHP requests find that they can't add to the file as it is locked?

Comment: yes, but they'll also block/wait until the lock is released. Unless you're writing out massive amounts of data to a slow storage system, then your locks will be acquired, data written, and then locks released very quickly.

Comment: My understanding is that file_put_contents() returns false if a lock is in place? Is that not right?

Comment: no idea. I don't normally use files that need write locks on them. I prefer databases for this sort of thing. I'd figure whichever php processes WANT a lock but can't get one because another process beat them to it would wait a while to acquire it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You mention you would use a DB for this kind of thing, but everything I read suggests using a DB for this isn't the best option. I'm guessing if I have any performance issues with the filesystem I'm also going to have them with the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your comments have made me think further and I've created a different question based on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266089/log-to-filesystem-or-database

Answer (score 0):

The right way to ask this question: Is file_put_contents guaranteed to be atomic?

It's almost certainly not, since you can write some pretty large streaks. You will want to use flock(), or otherwise use a more specialized logging system.