# Log to filesystem or database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using LAMP and have full access to server configuration and setup.

I am very confused about which is the best method to simply log some data to.

I want to log things like this:

- Analytics (server side with PHP) of every visitor.
- When creating a new user, store id number so an email and SMS message can be sent later in a Cron Task (saves from sending the email/SMS during the users' request).
- Number of page views of certain 'articles'. Increment once per visit to that page.

As you can see they are all simple insert/add actions that all can be processed later by a Cron Task.

The application needs to be scalable for the future.

These are my options (and what I have learned):

(1) Database (MySQL). People say don't use this for logging data like above.

(2) Use file_get_contents() WITHOUT a file lock. I'm told this can cause data corruption.

(3) Use file_get_contents() WITH a file lock but I believe this either results in missed data as file_get_contents returns false and doesn't add the data if the lock is in force -OR- it results in PHP having to wait for the lock to release. I don't think MySQL has to wait to do multiple inserts.

Which is the best option? Does it make a difference if I'm handling tens of requests per seconds compared to thousands of requests per second, or would I use the same option?

Comment: You don't have to [reinvent the wheel](http://www.google.ca/analytics/) for half of these things. For the new user/email/SMS thing, you should definitely use a MySQL database so entries are transaction based

Comment: bullet 2 should probably be logged separately, if at all. I would instead handle that on the user record with the created timestamp. If user was created in the last x minutes (x being the cron job interval), send user an email.

Comment: What kind of scale are you dealing with here? Hundreds? Millions? Billions? If it's just tens of thousands, put it in the database and don't waste your time trying to re-invent the wheel. You're going down the road of premature optimization pretty hard-core if you're talking about using flat files.

Comment: Why not use a database? The whole point of a database is to store structured data that can easily be read and manipulated according to your requirements... What email/SMS is to be sent and why do it later with cron? The user (upon registration completion) would normally want an immediate response...?

Comment: (1) Application handles about 50 million requests a day but needs to be able to scale up in future. (2) Also, there are various other tasks I want to delay and handle with a Cron Task to speed up server processing during users' requests. My examples were very basic to save waffling on and to prevent "why do you need this?" questions. As an example when adding a user it also makes a few other API calls. I do need to delay the processing as it's currently taking about 5 seconds to add a user. No human should have to wait that long. However, Kevin B's timestamp idea may be a good one.

Comment: (3) However, another requirement is where a user triggers something which then needs some processing that involves quite a few DB queries and inserts, so I am going to need to log to filesystem -OR- DB at least on a few occasions (and handle with a Cron Task later). It seems most people here say just go with the DB, but everywhere I read I hear that logging to the DB isn't good practice.

Comment: (4) Also, one comment says "If it's just tens of thousands, put it in the database and don't waste your time trying to re-invent the wheel". I would actually think the opposite. To simply add some data (e.g. analytics) to a log file that is briefly looked at by a human every now and then is that little bit easier than creating and configuring a new database table. I would say using the filesystem can be a lot easier on many occasions.